# Is it possible to get firefox to play MP4s in the html5 video tag?

Tags: javascript, flash, html

I know it is not right out of the box, but is there a hack anywhere that uses javascript, php, or even flash to play the MP4s if the html5 video tag isn't supported?

Comment: Not in the video tag as such, but through a Flash fallback, for example using video.js as konsolenfreddy suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several frameworks / plugins.

http://videojs.com/ for example provides good fallback.

It basically detects if HTML5 video is available and if not, it uses a provided flash player automatically. To change the order of used engines, you can set the option:

```
_V_.options.techOrder = ["swfH5"];
```

which will use `swf` before `HTML5`

The [compatibility chart](http://videojs.com/#compatibilitychart)  has a list of all browsers/technologies available for playback.

Comment: How does it provide flash fallback? I cannot find the documentation anywhere on the site. Any ideas?